# Generic non pnp monitor custom resolution

Tags: drivers, display, resolution, gpu, amd-radeon

I've ran into a problem with my monitor when updating it to the latest AMD drivers. normally my resolution is 1920x1080, but now since the driver update it's   downed to 1600x1200. In the advanced screensettings I can't see the option for the 1920x1080 resolution. This is not the first time that I had this problem. I always deleted the new drivers and installed the old drivers for my GPU. After that I was able to manage the EDID settings so I could set an custom resolution.

I don't want to go back to the old drivers, because I am a pc gamer and some games don't support the old drivers. Is there maybe a solution for this problem?? I've already looked for a solution but nothing worked for me.

Comment: What OS, what card, what drivers, how is it connected? If it's something ancient like VGA, or you have a string of video adaptors like an xmas tree, then expect to have to manually tweak the EDID every time - or switch to something that carries the info correctly.

Comment: Hi, I'm using a HD7850 on Windows 10 with the AMD radeon sofwareversion 16.12.1 CRIMSON. I'm using a VGA cable, but the end of the VGA which is going into the GPU is converted to DVI.

Comment: If the monitor has nothing other than VGA, then you're probably stuck. If it has, try it.